# eth.getBlock("latest").number is always 0 in Rinkeby testnet?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

In Rinkeby testnet blocks are importing but BlockNumber always shows zero only.I did transaction also for my account thatt block was downloaded but balance also not updated It shows in blockexplorer but not in show in the geth console

These are the commands I ran
1)geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby init rinkeby.json
2)geth --rinkeby --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=512 --ethstats="gopifullnode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io" --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303 --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
Output for the above command
[image]

3)geth attach ipc:\.\pipe\geth.ipc

Blocks are importing but in javascript console it shows 0 only
Following screen shots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here, tried `geth attach --rinkeby` but also connecting via node and web3js 1.0 - to no avail. Always 0 is returned, even though the blocks are imported....